# How to make list items created by javascript sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
        $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
    });
    </script>


<div class="demo">

<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

I want to make the list sortable after appending to it another item by ajax , how I could do that ?

Comment: Inside the ajax `success:function(){` you need to call `$('#sortable').sortable()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After appending new list items within in ajax `success: function() {...}` you can try:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable('destroy').sortable().disableSelection();
```

For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '',
  type: '',
  success: function() {
    // all codes to append new list items
    // then add following line

    $( "#sortable" ).sortable('destroy').sortable().disableSelection();

    // do something else if need
  }
});
```